# home\ end keys in xterm not behaving correctly

Tags: key-bindings, xterm

While I'm opening an xterm from my tsh at work, the `Home` and `End` keys scroll the xterm screen up and down respectively instead of moving to the beginning\ end of the line.
According to `/etc/inputrc`, my key binding is:

> > "\e[1~":        beginning-of-line
> >     "\e[4~":        end-of-line
> >     ...
> >     "\e[H":         beginning-of-line
> >     "\e[F":         end-of-line

Which is exactly what every site I found on the subject suggested, and yet - with no use.

If it means anything, the `Ctrl-a`, `Ctrl-e` behave as they should, but since I'm used for other keying, I'm missing.

Needless to say, since it is a work computer, I don't have writing permissions to the `/etc/inputrc` file and nobody is willing to change it for me.

How can I bypass this problem?
Don't really care if the solution will be a change in some file or an option to add to the xterm command.

p.s. (thanks to comment)
Before asking, I tried setting the same binding in my ~/.inputrc file, didn't work either

Comment: `~/.inputrc` is a thing.

Comment: thumb up for reminding me about the .inptrc, but even when I have the correct binding in it, I still don't have the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to any possible setting in `.inputrc` (that doesn't scroll your **screen** up and down, though you could scroll through the **command-history**, etc).

If it's xterm (and not some other terminal), you can fix this with the `translations` resource, e.g., by using `xev` to identify the names for the home/end keys (**probably** just `home` and `end`), and using those names in a translation like this (in your X resources):

```
*VT100*translations:    #override \n\
          <key>home: string(0x1b) string("[1~") \n\
           <key>end: string(0x1b) string("[4~") \n
```

Solaris used to do this for the page-up/page-down keys, and (for instance) if you are using an old version such as Solaris 10, the advice in the xterm FAQ *[Why can't I use the pageup/pagedown keys?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_pageup)* is relevant.

Further reading:

- *[.Xresources or .Xdefaults?](https://superuser.com/questions/243914/xresources-or-xdefaults)* may be helpful.  Most of the comments on X resources assume that you use X only locally, on a desktop. If your use is more general than that, `.Xdefaults` (usually with the hostname appended) is the place to start.  Otherwise, `.Xresources` is useful.
- [Sven Maschek's XTerm app-defaults file](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/xterm/XTerm)

Comment: This is it. I already found this answer at other threads (such as http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85656/how-to-change-key-mapping-for-home-and-end-keys-in-xterm), but failed to find the right place to put the translation at. The answer, btw, is `.Xresources` file I created for the occasion. Now I have Warning: translation table syntax error: Unknown event type :   key ... found while parsing '<key>home: string(0x1b) string("[1~") ', but it seems to work, so I hope nothing crashes in the near future..

Comment: The usual problem with syntax in `translations` is omitting a newline, `\n` (literally that).

Comment: If only I could, I would have given you another upvote for the editing you did, great links! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. `vim ~/.inputrc`  , If the file does not exist, create it
2. Add the following content to the file

   `"\e[1~": beginning-of-line`

   `"\e[4~": end-of-line`
3. `vim ~/.bashrc` , add `export INPUTRC=~/.inputrc` at the end of the file
4. `source ~/.bashrc`
5. Restart the terminal(Xshell)